# Clarification regarding the definition of a literal in C++

Tags: c++, literals

I believe I have been given some confusing information, so I am looking for a clarification.

When talking about literals (literal constants), is every value that is typed into the source code directly by the programmer considered to be a literal?

e.g.
`int x{5}; // Would the value of 5 in the initialized variable x be considered a literal?`

I understand the variable itself is not a literal as it can be changed, but would you refer to the 5 as per being a literal as it was typed directly into the source code and thus this specific value 5 cannot be changed without editing the source code?

Comment: Yes.  `5` is a literal.  `x` is a variable.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Where is the confusing information? What do you need clarified?

Comment: The opening sentence of your question describes the existence of information that caused confusion, yet you did not add that information to your question.  Now, we can only speculate what that was.  I imagine it might have been related to _constants_ and how the compiler is free to use a constant as if it were a literal (for primitive types).

Comment: A value is not a literal. A literal *represents* some value. Values exist at runtime, literals are a compile-time concept.

Comment: I do apologize as it seems to be a redundant clarification of information I stated which appears to be true. In a tutorial I am going through, it differentiates a variable and literal as the variable not being a literal as the value can be changed, while clearly the variable can hold a literal assuming it is initialized in it.  The apples to oranges comparison and differentiation between a variable and literal was confusing to me, and I thought that I may be incorrect in the assumption a literal is said inserted value. My understanding of constants was also adding confusion to the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's lots of literals:

- integer literals like `10`, `012`, `0xA`
- floating-point literals like `10.0`, `10.0f`
- boolean literals like `true`, `false`
- character literals like `'t'`, `'e'`, `'n'`
- string literals like `"ten"`
- null pointer literal like `nullptr`
- user-defined literals like `"10"h`.